# How to generate random numbers fast from "An Extremely Big Array" in Python？

Tags: python, numpy, random, sample

Recently, I got stuck searching for a fast way to generate random numbers in Python. Here like the code below, I collect points from an area with more than 10 million points. And I want to sample 8192 points randomly from the area points. However, `np.random.choice(np.arange(...))` makes the program so slow since the large index arrays.

So, how to make this procedure faster? With any useful Python package or function? Thanks for your attention!

```py
import numpy as np

area_idx = self.area_idxs[idx]
points = self.area_points[area_idx]  # 14350962 * 3
labels = self.area_labels[area_idx]  # 14350962
npoints = 8192
# np.random.choice(np.arange(...)) makes the program so slow.
selected_point_idxs = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(points)), npoints, replace=False)
```

Generate random numbers fast from "An Extremely Big Array" in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy mentioned in the document that new code should use the new [random generator](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generator.html#random-generator) to generate random numbers (refer to note in [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)), and the new random generator will have better performance in `choice`:

```
In [_]: n, k = 14350962, 8192

In [_]: %timeit np.random.choice(np.arange(n), k, replace=False)
772 ms ± 10.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [_]: %timeit np.random.choice(n, k, replace=False)
742 ms ± 8.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [_]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [_]: %timeit rng.choice(np.arange(n), k, replace=False)
19.1 ms ± 98.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [_]: %timeit rng.choice(n, k, replace=False)
147 µs ± 687 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

And when indices are directly generated by `np.arange`, the same result can be obtained by passing only the length, avoiding the construction of indices.

#### Some supplements

In the new [`Generator.choice`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/_generator.pyx#L896), for cases where k is small, the numpy team uses Floyd's sampling algorithm with a time complexity of `O(k)`, while the old [`RandomState.choice`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L1026) always uses a random permutation with a time complexity of `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `np.take` function.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 2],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [2, 2, 2],
  [1, 2, 3]
])
npoints = 3
point_ids = np.random.choice(a.shape[0], npoints)
points = np.take(a, point_ids, axis=0)

# print(points)
# [[1 2 3]
# [1 2 3]
# [2 2 2]]
```